# haxe: How to use enum values of concrete enum type in generic class?

Tags: generics, types, enums, haxe

I'd like to make generic class that works with passed enum type, like this:

```
class Holder<E, T> { // I suppose to pass only enum types as E, how to limit them?

    function new() {
        mMap = new Map<EnumValue, T>();
    }

    function add(aKey:EnumValue, aValue:T) { // aKey is practically ANY enum value
        mMap.set(aKey, aValue);
    }

    var mMap:Map<EnumValue, T>; // what type should I use as key? like E<EnumValue>

}

enum Keys {
    A;
    B;
}

enum Injection {
    NOT_ALLOWED;
}

// first drawback
var holder = new Holder<Keys, String>();
holder.add(Keys.A, "This is A");
holder.add(Keys.B, "This is B");
holder.add(Injection.NOT_ALLOWED, "Not allowed by design!"); // it must not be allowed

// second drawback
var strange = new Holder<String, String>(); // it must not be allowed too
```

I never use E type in class declaration because I don't understand how to propagate enum value back to it's type. And I can't just write `Holder<Enum<E>,T>` in class definition to use `E` type for enum values.
What should I do to limit `E` just as enum types and then get arguments only of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to specify a constrain on E, i.e. `E:EnumValue`, and change the type of `aKey` to `E` of your `add` function

full code:

```
package;

class Main {

    public static function main()
    {
        // first drawback
        var holder = new Holder<Keys, String>();
        holder.add(Keys.A, "This is A");
        holder.add(Keys.B, "This is B");
        holder.add(Injection.NOT_ALLOWED, "Not allowed by design!"); // compiler error: Injection should be Keys

        // second drawback
        var strange = new Holder<String, String>(); // compiler error: String should be EnumValue
    }
}

class Holder<E:EnumValue, T> { // constrain the type parameter "E" to be an "EnumValue"

    public function new() {
        mMap = new Map(); // actually you don't have to specify the type parameters when constructing the object
    }

    public function add(aKey:E, aValue:T) { // aKey is simply of type "E"
        mMap.set(aKey, aValue);
    }

    var mMap:Map<E, T>; 

}

enum Keys {
    A;
    B;
}

enum Injection {
    NOT_ALLOWED;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's look so simple but I haven't manage to make the last step.